# How to setup normal Icon for iPhone3 and Retina for iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, icons

I heard somewhere of an workaround by adding the following files to your xcode project:

- Icon.png - 57x57 pixels application icon for standard resolution iPhone
- Icon@2x.png - 114x114 pixels application icon for high resolution iPhone 4
- Icon-72.png - 72x72 pixels application icon for iPad
- Icon-Small.png - 29x29 pixels settings icon for standard resolution iPhone
- Icon-Small@2x.png - 58x58 pixels settings icon for high resolution iPhone
- Icon-Small-50.png - 50x50 pixels settings icon for iPad

Then setup your CFBundleIconFile to "Icon" (without extention).

The compiler will put a warning because your icon does not have an extention. If you just ignore it - it will work like a charm - UNTIL YOU WANT TO UPLOAD YOUR BINARY!

If you upload your binary through webinterface everything is working fine - but if you use the "apploader" it will not upload your app because of the missing extention..

is there a known way how to setup correctly the icons so you can use it for iPhone3 and iPhone4?

There is a "CFBundleIconFiles" Key for iPhone 3.2 and later - is it possible to use both?

Answer (score 3):

Just set the `Icon` filename to `Icon.png` or delete the key all together from the `info.plist` file and let the OS do the work for you.  It will select the correct one based on the device.

As long as both an `Icon.png` and an `Icon@2x.png` are added to the app bundle, the OS will load the correct one.

Comment: If you just rename ´Icon´ to ´Icon.png´ it will only use Icon.png on all devices. But this will do it : 

First remove CFBundleIconFile, then add a dictionary key called CFBundleIconFiles (with s at the end!) and finally add all your Icon Files to this dictionary (item 0 : Icon.png, item 1: Icon@2.png etc.) that will work.

Comment: Whatever works for you!  I just delete the key all together from `info.plist` and add both icon files to my bundle and the OS deals with it just fine.  One less thing to manage.

Answer (score 3):

See Apple's [Technical Q&A QA1686](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1686.html) which describes the exact naming conventions, Info.plist keys, and other details for the various icon sizes required for each device.