# Setting multiple icon files

Tags: iphone, icons, app-store, distribution

I'm in the final stretch of submitting an application for distribution in the iTunes store, but I'm getting hung up on the icon files!

If I have only a 57x57 file, I get a warning in XCode and an error in Application Loader that I haven't provided a 72x72. If I set the 72x72's name to "Icon.png" instead of the 57x57, then it complains that it needs a 57x57 and chokes on the Application Load step.

Apple has addressed this already at:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1686.html#IPHONEADDITEMS, but those instructions are failing when I try to follow them: No disclosure arrow ever appears next to the "Icon files" key once I've added it, so the method there for adding multiple icons is failing for me.

On a related note, I don't actually WANT the 72x72 icon for iPad. I've set the application properties to iPhone only, yet it continues to demand the 72x72 icon in addition to the 57x57.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup normal Icon for iPhone3 and Retina for iPhone 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389160/how-to-setup-normal-icon-for-iphone3-and-retina-for-iphone-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here were the assorted issues:

1) I had to manually set the type of CFBundleIconFiles to Array by right clicking on it after changing the name. However, that got rolled back as...

2) Application Loader's schizophrenic insistence that the sole icon be both 57x57 and 72x72 at the same time was because I had set the "Base SDK" to 3.2 in the Project properties, an OS version which is iPad only, at the same time that I set the "Targeted Device Family" to compile for iPhone only. The solution was to change the "Base SDK" to 4.0 but the "iPhone OS Deployment Target" to 3.1.3, while leaving iPhone as the "Targeted Device Family".

Now I'm compiling without warnings. The new hang up is that Application Loader just says there was an error communicating with the iTunes store. :P

Comment: Follow up: Debugging the "Error Communicating with iTunes Store" bug was miserable, but it's sorted now, too. The issues I ran into there and how they were resolved are recorded here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680916/three-itunesconnect-gotchas

Answer (score 0):

You can get the disclosure arrow to appear by clicking the icon on the far right side of the row when it's selected to get the first one, then click the plus to get the next one.  That is really the recommended way of doing it.  Apple actually recommends 57x57 (iPhone), 114x114 (iPhone4), 72x72 (iPad), and 512x512 (Ad-Hoc Distribution) icons be in there.

Better yet, I sometimes find going to the new "Preview Release 2" of XCode 4 and using it to modify the Info.plist is the way to go-- a MUCH nicer editor and apparently forward and backward file compatibility.  Then open it back up in XCode 3 and do your final compiles there.

Comment: The plus icon didn't work for me, but after changing the name to CFBundleIconFiles I was able to right click the blank space next to it and select Value Type -> Array. Having done that, I gained the ability to right click and select Add Row. Now I have two entries, one for Icon.png, and a second for Icon-72.png. And now it complains that Icon-72 isn't 57x57!

Comment: Correction: Once the value type was changed to an array, the side button DID start to work to add icons.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care how your app looks on an iPad, the quick & dirty solution is to create a 72 by 72 pixel icon file (just copy and resize your current one using the Preview app) and include it in your project resources as Icon-72.png