# iPhone Icon@2x.png not showing in Retina display

Tags: iphone, icons, plist

For some reason, the iPhone 4 refuses to display my high resolution icon file.

I've checked out these solutions, none of which have worked for me:

[How to setup normal Icon for iPhone3 and Retina for iPhone 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389160/how-to-setup-normal-icon-for-iphone3-and-retina-for-iphone-4)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1686.html

http://appworks.radeeccles.com/programming/cfbundleiconfiles-nice-ready-prime-time/

The icons are in my resources group, and are all named correctly:

- Icon.png
- Icon@2x.png
- Icon-72.png

I've also tried adding them to the Info.plist file, first as an array, then as a dictionary, then simply deleting all icon references from the plist file, but no matter what I do, it still displays the 57x57 icon scaled up.

Can someone who has a working icon setup please post the actual XML incantation required to make this work?

Comment: It should.... What is your SDK version ? didn't you forget the I (and wrote icon@2x.png ?) Did you try a clean / compile ?

Comment: Tried all of that.  No dice.  This is on SDK 4.1 with the latest xcode.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**My Solution was simple, but only caught it be painstakingly comparing line-by-line in Apple Docs.**

The non-obvious solution that seamed contradictory was "Deleting the Icon file key value".  In the previous answer's image, you can see the Icon file still shows "icon.png" and the "Icon files" shows the two: icon.png & icon@2x.png.

I got my app to work by deleting the "Icon file's" key value of "Icon.png"  It was the only thing different, in the Apple Docs was the absence of a value for the "Icon file" key.  View an image here: link removed...

Updated Link that Shows these Images:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1686/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009882

In addition, I would make sure you are using Apples recommended notation when labeling the photos:

> - 512x512    iTunesArtwork           iTunes Image
> - 57x57  Icon.png            Home screen for < iPhone 4
> - 114x114    Icon@2x.png             Home screen for iPhone 4 High Resolution
> - 72x72  Icon-72.png             Home screen for iPad compatibility
> - 29x29  Icon-Small.png          Spotlight and Settings
> - 50x50  Icon-Small-50.png   Spotlight for iPad compatibility
> - 58x58  Icon-Small@2x.png       Spotlight and Settings for iPhone 4
>     High Resolution

---

**Next Steps...**

1. Clean All targets
2. Reset Simulator
3. Relaunch Application
4. Works fine for iPhone4, reveals large AppIcon = "Icon@2x.png"

---

**Final Steps...**

1. I put the "Icon.png" name back in for the (Icon file) key.
2. I put this back in to Backwards support iOS 3.0+ so that it still has a value to use.
3. Clean All Targets again,
4. Build & Relauch!

---

This methods seams to clear out any legacy issues and assures that the simulator pulls in the correct files.

Hopes this helps!

P.S. If this helps you solve your problem, be sure to check my comment as the Solution.

Comment: Worked for me too! I had a different problem where I renamed my project and the icon will not longer display in simulator and the device. Your solution fixed that :)

Comment: Can anyone comment on the resolution of the images? Should these images be rendered at a standard 72dpi  or the higher 96dpi? I only ask because the WP7 standards ask for the higher and it's a pain to have two sets of icons to maintain. Thanks!

Comment: This is a nice psd template for the actual icon creation http://blog.cocoia.com/2010/iphone-4-icon-psd-file/

Comment: Great, I always forget exactly how to do this little dance. Thanks so much.

Comment: Link to "Info.plist Apple Docs Image" is dead.

Comment: @EmileCormier: Yeah that was back in 2010.  Try this link that will bring you to the most recent Source:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009882

Answer (score 17):

**i had this problem too... this is how I managed to fix it**

in your info.plist file you need two entries:

the first one will be "icon file" and this needs to be "Icon.png".

the second entry will be "icon files" and this is an array...

the FIRST ENTRY in the array is your icon file at std def: "Icon.png"

the SECOND ENTRY is the icon file at high def: "Icon@2x.png"

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is basically what is written in the Apple documentation.  I have the case correct and the filenames are exact.  It still shows the low res icon in the iPhone 4.

Comment: are you sure high-res image is not corrupt. I know that a lot of the time I accidentally save PSDs as PNGs without changing the file-type, just the extention.

Comment: sorry... you're doing it right... there must be something else wrong. Are you installing it on an iphone 4? Have you tried deleting the app and reinstalling it? Are you sure the @2x icon isn't the same as the std def one? Are you sure its 114x114 and you haven't accidentally saved it at 57x57? Erm... not much else I can think it could be

Comment: Yeah, I've checked all that.  I was just hoping someone could post the actual XML so I could compare mine to one that actually works.

Comment: well you've got my screenshot... not much more to the acctual XML

Comment: The problem is that visual editors often lie, which is why I'm looking for the actual XML.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and tried the "Icon files" array entry in info.plist without success.

What I did to get it to work was delete all "Icon file", and "Icon files" entries in info.plist as well as in the Properties tab in your Project Settings.  Then just used the Apple naming conventions for all my files

```
    * 512x512 iTunesArtwork iTunes Image
    * 57x57 Icon.png Home screen for < iPhone 4
    * 114x114 Icon@2x.png Home screen for iPhone 4 High Resolution
    * 72x72 Icon-72.png Home screen for iPad compatibility
    * 29x29 Icon-Small.png Spotlight and Settings
    * 50x50 Icon-Small-50.png Spotlight for iPad compatibility
    * 58x58 Icon-Small@2x.png Spotlight and Settings for iPhone 4 High Resolution
```

as posted by Newbyman.

I then did a clean and build.  iPhone will properly detect the named icons in the resource bundle and use the appropriate icon.  I test on iPhone4 as well as a 1st Gen iPhone running 3.1.3.  I am using iOS 4.2 and the latest xcode.  Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is add on info.plist "Icon files" (not "Icon file") and change this value type to Array (right click in "Icon Files"). After that add two rows (right click again) and type "icon.png" in the first one and "icon@2x.png" in the second one.

Comment: Yes, we've been over this before in the other solutions and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

seems ios4 dosent using @2x gramma on this topic.

In you plist file "Icon files"

add files
* icon57.png
* icon114.png

this works on my project.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Newbyman's solution, but it did not work. The problem seems to come around when you try to add the new icons to an older project and attempt to maintain 3.0 legacy... Somehow you can add the "Icon files" array totally correctly in info.plist and it still will keep the original low res icon on retina display....

My solution was ultimately to remove the info.plist completely and grab a new info.plist from a newer project that was working, and then change out the values for the icon name's and product based information so it matched the old info.plist basically exactly, but some legacy information must go away.. Make sure you check off "add as target" when adding back in the newer info.plist....

Comment: Also, make sure you add it only to the relevant target. By default, all targets are checked, so need to be careful there

Comment: And this is why it should be removed from Copy Bundle Resources of the relevant target: http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2008/Aug/msg00414.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, after much frustration, the only way I was able to get this working was to create a fresh target, and remove all references to icons from the plist file.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime it's necessary to remove icons, clean build, add icons back, run on device.
It helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had the issue crop up again.

What was actually happening was that the Icon@2x.png had actually been saved as a jpg file. So xcode would happily include the "png" image but iOS would have nothing of it.

XCode 4 actually checks this and complains, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

I just been having a load of trouble with this myself. I've come to the conclusion that the order of the icons within the array was the problem. I initially had the order as:

```
Icon.png
Icon-72.png
Icon@2x.png
```

This wouldn't work. However, when I changed it to this everything worked fine:

```
Icon.png
Icon@2x.png
Icon-72.png
```