# iPhone app icon showing up as blank after a project rename

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, icons, plist

I'm working on an app using the 4.2 iOS SDK and recently changed the name of the project to something else. It compiles and runs fine, but now the icon file defined in the info plist is no longer working. When I build and run, the app icon shows up at blank on both the simulator and my iPhone 4 device.

I've tried swapping out different image files but to no avail. I also cleaned my build and targets. Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did the path to the icon file change?

Comment: I don't think so. I didn't change any paths, only the project name. If there is some kind of path that I need to update, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually saw this answer and it worked!

[iPhone Icon@2x.png not showing in Retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916361/iphone-icon2x-png-not-showing-in-retina-display/3994558#3994558)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the rename caused something to not match in your info.plist so it is being ignored?

Comment: What matching are you referring to?