# Exporting iPhone appicon without loosing clarity?

Tags: iphone, ios, icons, titanium-mobile

I have a vector image which is larger than 57 x 57 pixels. I resized it to 57 x 57 with Adobe Illustrator and set it as my appicon, but it was blurred when I deployed it into my device.

What is the right way to create icons for my app when using Titanium Studio?

Comment: this has nothing to do with illustrator if it looks ok to you when you preview it.  Does it look ok off the device?

Comment: Yes it does look ok off the device.

Comment: is the device an ipad or a phone/touch?

Comment: What iPhone are you using? Don't forget Retina display iPhones need an @2x icon that is 144x144 px

Comment: Also there are a large number of icons required for iPhone development  more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916361/iphone-icon2x-png-not-showing-in-retina-display

Comment: @nycynik I'm using ipod touch.

Answer (score 1):

This link should help:

http://www.titaniumtips.com/files/creating_universal_titanium_apps.php

Especially the part about icons.

> 57x57px icon for the standard iPhone display. Before submitting to the
>   App Store, you’ll need to add icons for the iPhone Retina display (114x114) and
>   iPad (72x72). Optionally you can add icons for Spotlight and the Settings
>   pages too.

Comment: I'm already using the right size (57 x 57) and I'm using IPod touch. I want my icon to be displayed clearly. Thanks anyways.