# Iphone Application Icon Not Showing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, icons, emulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone Icon@2x.png not showing in Retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916361/iphone-icon2x-png-not-showing-in-retina-display)

While building an Iphone app, a problem that has plagued me is that I cannot seem to get my own icon to show on the emulator. Things I've tried:

1. Dragging the icon into the build summary -> App icons
2. Manually editing the Info.plist file
3. Turning off PNG compression
4. Renaming the file
5. Using a different file

I will also note that the launch image does work. I'm at a loss here, anything I might be missing? This is normally straightforward.

Comment: Delete the DerivedData and try again

Answer (score 0):

More info here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1686.html#IPHONEADDITEMS

Comment: Number 2 on my list of things I did....

Comment: with the same names ??, see the link i attached

Comment: As it turns out the issue was with the emulator. I will note you should be wary about quoting people without citing them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916361/iphone-icon2x-png-not-showing-in-retina-display